# Javascript function Element makes others JS function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script (not made by myself) in order to show markers in Google MAP API with Markerclustering. I've included this script to one of my page and since then, my jQuery code doesn't work anymore.

I've started debugging with `console` etc, and I've found what causes the issue, it's this function that is on the top of the page of the marker_cluster JS script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="speed_test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', speedTest.init);
</script>
<script src="vendors/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=speedTest.init">
</script>
```

```js
function $(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}

var speedTest = {};

speedTest.pics = null;
speedTest.map = null;
speedTest.markerClusterer = null;
speedTest.markers = [];
speedTest.infoWindow = null;

speedTest.init = function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.91, 116.38);
  var options = {
    // 'zoom': 10,
    // 'center': latlng,
    // 'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.188, 6.12701),
    gestureHandling: "greedy",
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  speedTest.map = new google.maps.Map($('map'), options);
  speedTest.pics = data.photos;

  var useGmm = document.getElementById('usegmm');
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(useGmm, 'click', speedTest.change);

  var numMarkers = document.getElementById('nummarkers');
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(numMarkers, 'change', speedTest.change);

  speedTest.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  speedTest.showMarkers();
};
```

When I comment this portion of code:

```
function $(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

then my jquery code works back again, but then the Google Map API doesn't show anymore. I think it's because it's a general function... And it must interract with all the function of the page, and that's causing the issue.

You can find this [code here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/speed_test_example.html).

The [file in question here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/speed_test.js):

If you have any clue how I can fix this issue I'd really appreciate =)

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` refers to `jQuery` and you are changing it by declaring below function

```
function $(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Use some other name for function instead of `$`.Maybe you can use `e`

```
function e(element) {
  return document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, didn't know that $ is a reference to Jquery =O I've tried then to rename all the function name $ by another and it works out... Well, thank you very much ! Maybe I should start to look for some Jquery courses.